# Is it bad practice to stuff garbage into $array[-1] to prevent OBOB?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a bunch of nested if statements that are somewhat as follows:

```
if (strcmp($data['reports'][$i][$j],$data['reports'][$i][$j-1])){
```

but as you all know, you have to write a separate if statement if it is 0, because 0-1 doesn't exist.

```
    if ($j == 0){
 //First report, to prevent OBOB
        echo "<br/><a href = ".$filename.">".$data['reports'][$i][$j]."</a>";

#-> You would have to write two more statements here to test for province...
}

    if ($j >= 1){
 //All subsequent reports
      if (strcmp($data['reports'][$i][$j],$data['reports'][$i][$j-1])){
        echo "<br/><a href = ".$filename.">".$data['reports'][$i][$j]."</a>";
#-> You would have to write two more statements here to test for province...
    }
```

Now, imagine if you have to test other dependent values for sequential identicality?

It goes from 4 to 8 to 16 separate statements to just test for 4 of these...

So, I just had the idea to stuff crap into $j = -1.

```
        $data['reports'][$i][-1]='aaaaaaaaaa'; 
// This would depend on the type of data you are
// comparing I suppose it could be zeros.
        $data['provinces'][$i][-1]='aaaaaaaaa';
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just start your loop with 1 instead of 0? That is, instead of this:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($data['reports'][$i]); $j++ )
```

do this:

```
for ($j = 1; $j < count($data['reports'][$i]); $j++ )
```

It's pointless to compare the first array element to the previous one anyway, so just skip it.

Comment: I suppose I could. There are other things inside the loop that are non-comparative in nature, where they really should start at 0. Like, sorting alphabetically. You should start at element 0, right? Do you think separating these out of the same loop is a good idea?

Comment: @RVWard - maybe you can split it out then? Like, loop over the array twice - the first time start with 0 and do your sorting and stuff; the second time start with 1 and do the comparisons. The overall efficiency won't suffer much from this.

Comment: That is a good idea, and much less embarrassing to show my fellow coders. Lol.

Comment: Or, do the loop from `$j = 0`, but test for non-null `$j` before each comparison: `if ($j && strcmp($data['reports'][$i][$j],$data['reports'][$i][$j-1]))`. This way, the order of execution is unchanged from your original code, and it doesn't look ugly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, how can I start at 1 when there are elements at 0? They are getting passed over when I start at 1. If I start at 1, I will have the same problem, because I will have to make an exception to print 0 anyways, which leads me back into geometrical replication of code... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to do something with the first element, Vilx's answer is the way to go. By the looks of your code, you always echo the first element, and the others need an if condition. I'm guessing your concerned about duplicate code (good), just move the code that echos a row into a new method and call it conditionally.